# R loop matching values in one dataframe with values in a second data frame, and writing them to a third dataframe

Tags: r

Basically I have `sumpwver` that is a list of a lot of projects and the costs of those projects.  I then have `negpw` which is only the negative projects in `sumpwver`.  With the loop I'm trying to determine how many positive values in `sumpwver` match the negative values in `negpw`.  when I run the loop there are no errors, but it only creates one row in matches and I know there are more instances.  For example, you can see from the head of both sets that the first two rows of `sumpwver` should be listed as a match.

Also, the really weird thing is that when I try and find the row in the `sumpwver` set that corresponds with the dollar value pulled into matches, it won't recognize it.  But, if I search sumpwver by the project number, it will.

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

```
(dput(droplevels(head(pw))))
structure(list(Disaster.Number = c(1310L, 1310L, 1310L, 1310L, 
1310L, 1310L), PW.Number = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), Version.Number = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Total.Obligated = c(316180, -316180, 2659.69, 
345794.29, -28929.91, 40344.08)), .Names = c("Disaster.Number", 
"PW.Number", "Version.Number", "Total.Obligated"), .internal.selfref =  <pointer: (nil)>, row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")) 

  Disaster.Number PW.Number Version.Number Total.Obligated
1            1310         1              0       316180.00
2            1310         2              0      -316180.00
3            1310         3              0         2659.69
4            1310         4              0       345794.29
5            1310         4              1       -28929.91
6            1310         5              0        40344.08



sumpwver <- setDT(pw)[,.(Total.Obligated=sum(Total.Obligated)),
    by = .(dr.pw=paste(Disaster.Number, PW.Number, sep="pw"))]`

(dput(droplevels(head(sumpwver))))
structure(list(dr.pw = c("1310pw1", "1310pw2", "1310pw3", "1310pw4", 
"1310pw5", "1310pw6"), Total.Obligated = c(316180, -316180, 2659.69, 
316864.38, 40401.82, 162751.59)), .Names = c("dr.pw", "Total.Obligated"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: (nil)>, row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

    dr.pw Total.Obligated
1 1310pw1       316180.00
2 1310pw2      -316180.00
3 1310pw3         2659.69
4 1310pw4       316864.38
5 1310pw5        40401.82
6 1310pw6       162751.59

negpw <- sumpwver[sumpwver$Total.Obligated < 0,]

(dput(droplevels(head(negpw))))
structure(list(dr.pw = c("1310pw2", "1310pw10", "1310pw37", "1310pw268", 
"1310pw270", "1311pw10"), Total.Obligated = c(-316180, -1742.78, 
-0.01, -8679.84, -76.34, -3835294.19)), .Names = c("dr.pw", "Total.Obligated"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: (nil)>, row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

      dr.pw Total.Obligated
1   1310pw2      -316180.00
2  1310pw10        -1742.78
3  1310pw37           -0.01
4 1310pw268        -8679.84
5 1310pw270          -76.34
6  1311pw10     -3835294.19


matches <- data.frame(dr.pw=character(), Total.Obligated=numeric(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

for (i in nrow(negpw)) {
if (any(sumpwver$Total.Obligated == abs(negpw$Total.Obligated[i]))) {
    matches[nrow(matches)+1,"Total.Obligated"] <- negpw$Total.Obligated[i] 
    matches[nrow(matches),"dr.pw"] <- negpw$dr.pw[i]
} 
} 

(dput(droplevels(head(matches))))
structure(list(dr.pw = "4211pw133", Total.Obligated = -7.27595761418343e-12), .Names = c("dr.pw", 
"Total.Obligated"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")


      dr.pw Total.Obligated
1 4211pw133   -7.275958e-12

sumpwver[sumpwver$Total.Obligated==-7.275958e-12,]
[1] dr.pw           Total.Obligated
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

sumpwver[sumpwver$Total.Obligated=="-7.275958e-12",]
[1] dr.pw           Total.Obligated
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

sumpwver[sumpwver$Total.Obligated==-7.275958*10^-12,]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: dr.pw,Total.Obligated

sumpwver[sumpwver$dr.pw=="4211pw133",]
           dr.pw Total.Obligated
626721 4211pw133   -7.275958e-12
```

Comment: Share some data with `dput()` please (`dput(droplevels(head(data)))` is usually good).

Comment: It looks like it could be related to [floating point precision](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/903061). You might want to use `all.equal()` instead of `==`, or better yet, multiply by 100 and convert to integers.

Comment: I used all.equal as suggested in the link you provided with the following code, and now matches has 0 values instead of 1.

Comment: for (i in nrow(negpw)) {
    if (any(isTRUE(all.equal(sumpwver$Total.Obligated, abs(negpw$Total.Obligated[i]))))) {
        matches[nrow(matches)+1,"Total.Obligated"] <- negpw$Total.Obligated[i] 
        matches[nrow(matches),"dr.pw"] <- negpw$dr.pw[i]
    } 
}

Comment: Have any more ideas Gregor?

Comment: Multiply by 100 and convert to integers, as I said before. Should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I got the same weird value with using *100 (code below).  I'm not sure its a floating point precision issue.  There must be something else wrong.  Maybe the way I created matches doesn't allow for more values to be added?

Comment: for (i in nrow(negpw)) {
        if (any((sumpwver$Total.Obligated * 100) == abs(negpw$Total.Obligated[i] * 100))) {
            matches[nrow(matches)+1,"Total.Obligated"] <- negpw$Total.Obligated[i] 
            matches[nrow(matches),"dr.pw"] <- negpw$dr.pw[i]
        } 
    }